# Noindex 4000 urls using x-tag-robots via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, noindex, x-robots-tag

I need to noindex 4000 URLs.
I wanna do it using x-robots-tag via htaccess, but I don't want to overload the htaccess with such infinite list of URLs, so...

The idea would be to create the list in a separate file (noindexurls.txt) and then using a specific htaccess rule to noindex all the 4000 URLs included in that **external file**.

Is it possibible? What should be the proper htaccess rule in that case?

......pls note that no category, directory or pattern can be used in this case.

Comment: Only way I could see that could somehow work would be by using a [`RewriteMap`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) - but that can't be configured in .htaccess context.